# print with .pdf without prompting dialog box

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I am new to VBA and still trying to learn this day by day. I need to print my opened workbook with a .PDF format but without prompting the print dialog box(Destination folder). Instead, I want to format a destination path in the code and also with some page setups(orientation,zoom,etc). How do I solve this?

```
Sub PrintDoc()
Sheets("Sheet1").PrintOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you prevent printing dialog when using Excel PrintOut method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219/how-do-you-prevent-printing-dialog-when-using-excel-printout-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to define your destination path and print PDF without prompting the print dialog box and some basic page set-ups.

```
'Export as PDF
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    destinationPath & destinationFilename & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Attribution: [Another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689566/3468139)

Comment: ,I would like to thank for being kind to answer my question and  helped me to solve this.Actually it worked.Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Nilusha. Request you to accept my answer by clicking the tick on the left of my answer. Glad, it helped you.